# format change in R

Tags: r, format

Is there any chance to calculate network statistics with the package plotrix. I tried this previously and there are some available tools but not soemtimes other utilitites like ultimatnet are faster

Answer (score 1):

It's seriously hard to answer questions about unusual packages without reproducible examples. Please notice how I load an example datafile from a package so others can reproduce my example.

```
library(ape)
library(phytools)
data("hivtree.newick")
tree = read.tree(hivtree.newick)
str(tree)

# List of 4
#  $ edge       : int [1:384, 1:2] 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 ...
#  $ Nnode      : int 192
#  $ tip.label  : chr [1:193] "A97DCA1EQTB52" "A97DCA1MBFE185" "A97DCA1MBS12" "A97DCA1MBS30" ...
#  $ edge.length: num [1:384] 0.012112 0.000001 0.015665 0.029972 0.003031 ...
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
#  - attr(*, "order")= chr "cladewise"
```

Our first observation is that this structure only has text labels for the 193 tips. Therefore, we can't hope to get text labels for the internal nodes from `tree`, since they're not stored in `tree`. However, the tree has nodes numbered 1 to 385; we can figure out which node numbers are internal with the `getDescendants` function:

```
is.internal = sapply(1:385, function(x) length(getDescendants(tree, x)) > 1)
which(is.internal)
#   [1] 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214
#  [22] 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235
#  [43] 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256
#  [64] 257 258 259 260 261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277
#  [85] 278 279 280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298
# [106] 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314 315 316 317 318 319
# [127] 320 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 331 332 333 334 335 336 337 338 339 340
# [148] 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 352 353 354 355 356 357 358 359 360 361
# [169] 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 378 379 380 381 382
# [190] 383 384 385
```

Comment: good to see that this is possible...just in case you do know the packages a bit is there a chance to find out about the time of nodes in the file? not the edge length but the time from the tips of the tree?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about these packages (or phylogenetics, for that matter). However, a simple search in the package documentation suggests `branching.times` in the ape package might be what you're looking for?

Comment: One quick thing -- it seems from your profile page that you have never upvoted an answer or accepted an answer, even though you've been getting some pretty good responses to your questions. Upvoting and accepting is an important part of using the StackOverflow website.